# OpenShift maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, openshift

I want to use openshift maven plugin to build the application in OpenShift.
I followed steps from : https://github.com/AhmedObaidi/openshift-maven-plugin

but when I do "mvn openshift:deploy" it downloads the openshift plugin in .m2 repository but build fails with the following error:

[INFO] --- openshift-maven-plugin:1.0.1:deploy (default-cli) @ mavenplugintest ---
[ERROR]

java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.obteq.maven.plugin.openshift.Openshift.execute(Openshift.java:53)

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)

Can anybody please help me how to use openshift maven plugin.
Additionally I saw one more plugin at : https://github.com/worldline/openshift-maven-plugin 
but not sure how to use this as there is no pluginrepository defined from where it can download the plugin.

Thanks a lot in advance for any of your support.

Thanks
Yashu

Comment: Hi , I haven't got any reply yet , please reply It will be really very helpful,

Answer (score 0):

You should post an issue on that project on github, since it is not an OpenShift maintained plugin.  The author would be the best one to answer your questions.